# Terrain Collision issues

Tags: c++, math, collision-detection, terrain

I'm trying to implement terrain collision for my height map terrain, and I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6E2zjfzMs7c). The tutorial is for java but I'm using C++, though the principles are the same so it shouldn't be a problem.

To start off we need a function to get the height of the terrain based on the camera's position. WorldX and WorldZ is the camera's position (x, z) and heights is an 2D-array containing all the heights of the vertices.

```
float HeightMap::getHeightOfTerrain(float worldX, float worldZ, float heights[][256])
{   
    //Image is (256 x 256)
    float gridLength = 256;
    float terrainLength = 256;

    float terrainX = worldX;
    float terrainZ = worldZ;
    float gridSquareLength = terrainLength / ((float)gridLength - 1);
    int gridX = (int)std::floor(terrainX / gridSquareLength);
    int gridZ = (int)std::floor(terrainZ / gridSquareLength);

    //Check if position is on the terrain
    if (gridX >= gridLength - 1 || gridZ >= gridLength - 1 || gridX < 0 || gridZ < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //Find out where the player is on the grid square
    float xCoord = std::fmod(terrainX, gridSquareLength) / gridSquareLength;
    float zCoord = std::fmod(terrainZ, gridSquareLength) / gridSquareLength;
    float answer = 0.0;

    //Top triangle of a square else the bottom
    if (xCoord <= (1 - zCoord))
    {
        answer = barryCentric(glm::vec3(0, heights[gridX][gridZ], 0),
        glm::vec3(1, heights[gridX + 1][gridZ], 0), glm::vec3(0, heights[gridX][gridZ + 1], 1),
        glm::vec2(xCoord, zCoord));
    }

    else 
    {
        answer = barryCentric(glm::vec3(1, heights[gridX + 1][gridZ], 0),
        glm::vec3(1, heights[gridX + 1][gridZ + 1], 1), glm::vec3(0, heights[gridX][gridZ + 1], 1),
        glm::vec2(xCoord, zCoord));
    }

    return answer;
}
```

To find the height of the triangle the camera is currently standing on we use the baryCentric interpolation function.

```
float HeightMap::barryCentric(glm::vec3 p1, glm::vec3 p2, glm::vec3 p3, glm::vec2 pos)
{
    float det = (p2.z - p3.z) * (p1.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (p1.z - p3.z);
    float l1 = ((p2.z - p3.z) * (pos.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (pos.y - p3.z)) / det;
    float l2 = ((p3.z - p1.z) * (pos.x - p3.x) + (p1.x - p3.x) * (pos.y - p3.z)) / det;
    float l3 = 1.0f - l1 - l2;
    return l1 * p1.y + l2 * p2.y + l3 * p3.y;
}
```

Then we just have to use the height we have calculated to check for
collision during the game

```
float terrainHeight = heightMap.getHeightOfTerrain(camera.Position.x, camera.Position.z, heights);
    if (camera.Position.y < terrainHeight)
    {
        camera.Position.y = terrainHeight;
    };
```

Now according to the tutorial this should work perfectly fine, but the height is rather off and at some places it doesn't even work. I figured it might have something to do with the translation and scaling part of the terrain

```
    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.3f, -15.0f));
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
```

and that I should multiply the values of the heights array by 0.1, as the scaling does that part for the terrain on the GPU side, but that didn't do the trick.

**Note**

In the tutorial the first lines in the getHeightOfTerrain function says

```
float terrainX = worldX - x;
float terrainZ = worldZ - z;
```

where x and z is the world position of the terrain. This is done to get the player position relative to the terrain's position. I tried with the values from the translation part, but it doensn't work either. I changed these lines because it doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> float terrainX = worldX - x;
> float terrainZ = worldZ - z;
> ```

Those lines are, in fact, very necessary, unless your terrain is *always* at the origin.

Your code resource (tutorial) assumes that you haven't scaled or rotated the terrain in any way. The `x` and `z` variables are the XZ position of the terrain which take care of cases where the terrain is translated.

Ideally, you should transform the world position vector from world space to object space (using the inverse of the `model` matrix you use for the terrain), something like

```
vec3 localPosition = inverse(model) * vec4(worldPosition, 1)
```

And then use `localPosition.x` and `localPosition.z` instead of `terrainX` and `terrainZ`.

Comment: I see, now I don't know if this sounds silly, but how could I find the Worldposition vector, as I only have a translation vector which offsets the local space position, but I don't know the local space position because it's different for every vertice and the GPU offsets each vertice individually with this translation vector? If you understand, what I mean? @Evil Tak

Comment: You only need the world space position of the bottom left corner (assuming the X, Y and Z axes point to the right, up and forward directions respectively) of the terrain.

Comment: Which could be found by checking the first index of the vector with all the vertices and then translating it: (0.0, 0.89, 0.0) + (0.0, -0.3, -15.0) = (0.0, 0.59, -15.0)?  (If I don't do any scaling) @Evil Tak

Comment: Yes. Don't translate it, instead transform (multiply) it with the `model` matrix. You should also store the terrain as an entity (just like you/the tutorial does with the camera) with public properties for things like position, rotation and scale. When you render the terrain, make sure that the bottom left corner is rendered at the position. The bottom left corner should be the pivot of the terrain. You can also make it work with keeping the world space position as the center of the terrain, but that'd require you to change your range check code a little bit.

Comment: It works! Thanks for all the help. I'll mark your post as the answer. @Evil Tak